# Check number of columns in uploaded excel-file

Tags: php, html, excel, fgetcsv

I'm creating a web page in which you have to upload a excel-file (either csv, xls or xlsx). 
Then I have to check the number of columns in the file, because the can must only contain TWO columns. I already find how to do this, but only for a csv-file:

```
if (($file = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE){
    while ($line = fgetcsv($file)){
        $numcols = count($line);
        if ($numcols != 2) {
            echo "The number of columns in your file is not correct. The file must contain only 2 columns. ";
            break;
        }
        $col = $line[0]; 
        echo "right! numcols = " . $numcols . "<br>";    
        break;
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Now, my question is: is it possible to use a similar function which can do this for all 3 file-formats?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps using a library that can read all three formats, such as [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php You can try use fgetcsv

Comment: @pvnarula - fgetcsv() isn't much help for BIFF formats .xls files, or for OfficeOpenXML format .xlsx files... and the OP is already aware of the function and its limitations

Comment: Use phpexcel it can tell you exactly how many columns are in all of the selected formats

Comment: @pvnarula: I already tried that function (see code). I'm searching for something that can also handle xls and xlsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use a library that can read the different formats. As Mark Baker pointed out [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) would be a good choice for the Excel formats.

Something like:

```
$colCount = checkExcelFile($path)

function checkExcelFile($path){
    $workbook = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

    // $column should then contain the highest column that is being used. 
    // It will be in the form A or B or AA etc. but if you are only expecting 2 columns,
    // then you would be expected 'B', so that would need to be converted to a number
    $column = $workbook->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();
    $colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($column);

    return $colNumber;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It works like a charm! The only comment, for future reference: the first line should be located after the function{ }

Comment: @user3037311 not sure why. As long as they are in the same file, you don't need to define the function first before using it. Thanks for accepting the answer though.